Can you clarify for me a passage in Paul J. Cohen's Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis (page 124)
In the proof of the Theorem on page 124, Cohen writes "For arbitrary $\gamma$", but $\gamma$ just doesn't seem to be a "free variable" in the verbiage that follows, so I'm not sure I'm digging what the passage is trying to say.  Can someone clarify this for me.
I'll try to attach the page in question


After further reflection, I suspect "For arbitrary $\gamma$" should not be read as a quantifier, but simply as a warning that the coming specification of $\gamma$ involves no rank or cardinality restriction.
But then I find Cohen again confusing when he defines the function $h$...
